# event report - export events added only

Tags: civievent, civireport

I want to run a report of events only. I want to be able to export the list of events to excel and share with my team. I don't care about fees or participants.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the Extended Reports extension there is a report called 'Event Overview' with which you can create a list of events. Just select the Event ID & Event Title columns to display and you should get a list. You can then export the list to CSV.